# Which method is better for multiple join and left join by Linq?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I have multiple table and I want **multiple join and left join** them together by **Linq**. I tried 2 different methods to achieve it and it seems both of them return correct results.

But *each method generate different SQL query*. For example *method 1* generate an `Order By` for some keys at end of the query too.

My question is:
**Which method do you recommend? Why** *(Performance &...)*?

**Method 1:**

```
    from t1 in Table1
    // Inner Join on a foreign key in tb1
    join t2 in Table2 on t1.fkId1 equals t2.Id1
    // Left Join
    join t3 in Table3 on t1.fkId1 equals t3.Id1 into ServCons
    from t3 in ServCons.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    // Left Join
    join t4 in Table4 on t3.Id2 equals t4.Id2 into t4
    select new{t1,t2,t3,t4}
```

[image]

**Method 2:**

```
    from t1 in Table1
    // Inner Join on a foreign key in tb1
    from t2 in Table2 .Where(w=>t1.fkId1 == t2.Id1)
    // Left Join
    from t3 in Table3 .Where(w=>t1.fkId1 == w.Id1).DefaultIfEmpty()
    // Left Join
    from t4 in Table4 .Where(w=>t3.Id2 ==w.Id2).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new{t1,t2,t3,t4}
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

I think it is clear that the **performance** is an important issue for a program and programmer. **Faster results with lower costs** is my target here too. So when i mentioned about **different SQL queries** with a question about performance it is clear enough that a good compare between 2 methods by writing about **pros and cons** of them will be accepted answer.

Comment: Better? In what aspect?

Comment: I don't think they return the same results. The first is an _inner join_, but isn't the second an _outer_ join? It may help if you also post the generated sql.

Comment: These look like different queries. And even if they are the same, only you can tell which is faster based on your data. Also the second query is mixing Linq styles which can be confusing.

Comment: @MaciejLos, I mentioned in my question:  `Why (Performance &...)?` also i describe about an additional `order by` in one of them so i think the question is clear enough.

Comment: @DavidG, I see the second method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199228/how-to-create-multiple-left-join-in-entity-framework)

Comment: "Performance & ..." is the same as saying "anything" which really makes this question too broad.

Comment: Agree with @DavidG. Note that, till the requirements are unspecified, an answer can be opinion based only. If you would like to get opinion in a specific aspect, you should define them.

Comment: @MaciejLos, I updated the question with SQL queries (name of the tables and columns are different in the SQL queries because i simplify them in Linq queries to make a clear question first).

Comment: @RAM.. Performance is totally dependant on your environment, schema, etc.  Try running both queries and see how they perform on your database. use SET STATISTICS IO ON and SET STATISTICS TIME ON to help make a decision.

Comment: @RAM The two syntaxes are equivalent in EF6 (although from the generated SQL looks like you are on EF Core), but in general depends on the query provider used - the first is the "official" *left outer join* LINQ pattern which theoretically should work in any query provider. However the 2 queries are not equivalent - the results have a different shape. `t4` in the first is a single object while in second - collection. In order to compare them, either make the first `... into t4j from t4 in t4.DefaultIfEmpty()` or make the second `let t4 = Table4 .Where(w=>t3.Id2 ==w.Id2).DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: @IvanStoev, thank you. You are right i should add `... into t4j from t4 in t4.DefaultIfEmpty()` at end of first. Now both of them generate exactly same queries and it is clear that the performance of equal queries are equal. Also you are right about _the first is the "official" left outer join LINQ pattern_ . I use EF6 in my project but these queries generated by LINQPad. If you write your comment as an answer i accept it.
Now, Is this a correct sentence? »» **After Correction, I can use the second method instead of the first method and both generates equal SQL query with equal performance.**

Comment: For EF6 - yes, that sounds correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the SQL difference is because the two queries are not equivalent.

In the first query:

```
join t4 in Table4 on t3.Id2 equals t4.Id2 into t4
```

is actually a [group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) which produces a different shape in the projection (`t4` is collection).

If you convert it to the `left outer join` LINQ pattern:

```
join t4 in Table4 on t3.Id2 equals t4.Id2 into t4Group
from t4 in t4Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

the generated SQL will be one and the same (depending on the query provider).

Now about performance. Since LINQ has no special `left outer join` operator, the first is the "officially" agreed LINQ pattern for implementing such operator. And LINQ to Objects it's definitely the way to go, because the `Enumerable.Join` implementation uses fast hash based lookup to perform the correlation woit O(n + m) time complexity, while `from ... .Where(...).DefaultIfEmpty()` is basically `SelectMany` with linear search operation with O(m * n) complexity.

For `IQueryable<T>` implementations, it really depends on the query provider. For EF6 provider both constructs are equivalent and gets translated to one and the same SQL. For EF Core - well, currently it's still in development and has many bugs and issues, especially with left joins, so it's hard to give you a general advice.

So for `IQueryable<T>` implementations, always check the query provider capabilities - what is supported or not, how it's translated / processed etc (LINQ is sort of broken in that regard).

In general I would say use the first pattern. Essential in LINQ to Objects and hopefully should be recognized by any good query provider.

But specifically for EF6, it's just a matter of a taste - since EF6 is smart enough to recognize and translate them to one and the same SQL, the performance is also one and the same.

Comment: I like the details that you provide in your answer. Thank you again.